# need to prepare email with body and body will contain graph

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net MVC 3 web application, where in some page I am showing a bar chart.

Now user is asking a "**mailto**" kind of link in that page and on clicking of that link, email client should open, where TO, Subject & Body will fill automatically and the **bar chart** should appear in body.

I know there is limitation of "mailto", we can prepare body with simple text like below, but is there any workaround to put graph within email body?

```
<A HREF="mailto:help@webcodehelpers.com?Subject=Help&Body=Hello%20%22Name%22%0A%0AWe%20are%20very%20happy%20for%20visiting%20our%20website%20webcodehelpers.com%20portal%2C%20which%20is%20providing%20useful%20information%20%2C%20code%20snippets%20and%20live%20examples.%0A%0AWe%20also%20providing%20Interview%20tip%20to%20all%20the%20freshers%20in%20web%20development%20and%20experienced%20people%20also%0A%0A%0AThanks%2C%0AWebCodeHelpers.com%20Team">Check Mail</A>
```

Comment: You will need to implement the email sending on the server. As you have already discovered the `mailto` link is pretty limited.

Comment: i agree, we can format email body with graph or image by sending to the server

Comment: yes, that's precisely what you need to do.

Comment: but, is there any way, we just somewhere prepare and hook up that to open with outlook client?

Comment: Outlook client? What if the user of your website is on Linux?

Comment: no, user are on windows always with outlook client always, no linux

Comment: I am afraid that what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: i understand, some time user are so funny :) they asking something non-sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mailto` protocol is pretty limited. You might need to send the email from your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

public void Sendemail()
    {
        try
        {

            Application oApp = new Application();
            MailItem oMsg = (MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem));

            // Set HTMLBody.
            const string emailSubject = "Auto Generated Email:Graph Screen Shot Update for";

            const string sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";

            const int iPosition = 50; // 

            const int iAttachType = (int)OlAttachmentType.olByValue;

            string htmlStart = "<html><body><h5><Font Color=Purpel>Hi,<br/>Please Find below The screen shot as of " + DateTime.Now + "<br/></h5>";
            string body = string.Empty;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"c:\Apps\download.jpg", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

            body += "<img src=\"cid:" + oAttach.FileName + "\" /><br/>";

            string wholeBody = htmlStart + body + "<h5><Font Color=Purpel>Note:Please check the graph.<br/>Regards,<br/>Md. Ajmal<br/><br/></h5></body></html>";

            oMsg.HTMLBody = wholeBody;
            // Set the subject.

            oMsg.Subject = emailSubject;

            //display

            oMsg.Display(oMsg);

            // Clean up.

            oMsg = null;

            oApp = null;

        }

        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```